# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, localhost

I am using this function to invoke the REST request, however, whenever I use the button to invoke this function, I get a connection refused. May I know how do I bypass this problem?

```
function getContacts() {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://localhost:5000/chaincode",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "827ed81a-b8b4-d6a5-7e2c-e36f955b7423"
        },
        "data": "{\r\n  \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",\r\n  \"method\": \"query\",\r\n  \"params\": {\r\n      \"type\": 1,\r\n      \"chaincodeID\":{\r\n          \"name\":\"mycc\"\r\n      },\r\n      \"ctorMsg\": {\r\n         \"function\":\"query\",\r\n         \"args\":[\"a\"]\r\n      }\r\n  },\r\n  \"id\": 1\r\n}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: simple enable cors to share data instead of using such way.

Comment: ^ + you should also provide an object to the `data` property and let jQuery encode it for you, instead of hacking together your own string.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is that the problem that is causing the localhost connection refuse issue?

Comment: No. You need to check the server to ensure it allows remote requests, and if not then enable CORS as @Jai suggested

Comment: @Jai sorry i am rather new to this 'cors' concept you are saying.. do you have any tutorials or examples to show on how to use it with REST api in jquery/ajax/javascript

Comment: It's not anything to do with JS - you need to put it on the server ie. The code you're running on `localhost:5000`. Exactly how you enable it varies on whatever framework the server uses. You should be able to find it by googling

Comment: For testing purposes you can use Chrome CORS plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I was using genymotion emulator, thus I couldn't bypass localhost. I used http://10.0.3.2/ as the host number. The problem was then solved.